# iOS - Swift Google AddMob SDK How to display different Ads in recurring items in UITableView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, admob, gadbannerview

**iOS - Swift Using of Google AddMob SDK How to display different Ads in recurring items in UITableView?**

The Below is the Sample link that i've created from [GoogleAdMob](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/quick-start?hl=en-US#import_the_mobile_ads_sdk).

[Sample GoogleAdMod Demo Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LQrGvQH57W6FnFuXG3VbCtKqDm8H4zid/view?usp=sharing)

**Currently on each recurring items same add is displaying, but i want to display different Ads in each recurring items.**

Attached screenshots for reference.

**Ad1 : Screenshot.**

[image]

**Ad2 : Screenshot.**

[image]

**Ad3 : Screenshot.**

[image]

**How can i achieve different Ads in each recurring items?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: your Ads in Test mode now. It will work when you switch to live mode.

Comment: @ShamsudheenTK : I am getting same adds in live mode also

Comment: Can you the code snippet to get more clarity because this is the case of the sandbox mode?

Answer (score 0):

I actually did the same in Objective C.
I have an array of dictionary to populate in the TableView. I inserted a dummy dictionary in every 4th index of the array , which is actually to identify that the cell belongs to google Ad.
In the UITableViewCell, just initialize GADBannerview  and GADRequest  and when you review the Ads in - (void)adViewDidReceiveAd:(GADBannerView *)adView ,just reload the corresponding index of the UITableView.